# i have used checkbox and onclick m taking out the row and saving it in array in react but on unchecking the checkbox the row is getting added again

Tags: reactjs

This is my code which taking the item from child and saving it in array in parent but when m unchecking the checkbox the item is getting added again
i cannot remove it from the array.
this is the function for which the checked item is pushed in the array but upon unclicking it is not getting removed

```
onRowSelection2=(x)=>{
var {selectedProcessList= []} = this.state
 selectedProcessList.push(x)
 
 this.setState( {selectedProcessList});
}
```

this is the onclick function in the child

```
<div className="mg-4"  ><input type="checkbox" onClick={()=>this.onSelected2(x)}/></div>
```

and the function code for this is

```
onSelected2=(x)=>{
            
        this.props.onSelect(x);
        }
```

and the onRowSelection2 is passed from the parent by passing props like this

```
onSelect={this.onRowSelection2}
```

Comment: How do you call `onRowSelection2`?

Comment: from the parent by passing props like this  onSelect={this.onRowSelection2}

Comment: I don't think the information you provided will be enough for debugging. You should provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: just give me some explanation on the checkbox i have created with input and passsed a function and in that argument i have send the item and pushed it in array now how unchecking the checkbox the item will be removed from the array

Comment: You don't check the value of the checkbox and you're listening to click events instead of `onChange`. As you don't check if the checkbox is checked, you call `onRowSelection2` on every single click.

Comment: can you please change my code and make me understand please